# How Do I PInvoke Into CommonCrypto CCKeyDerivationPBKDF?

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to PInvoke into the `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF` [here](http://opensource.apple.com//source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-55010/CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h).

The method signature looks like this:

```
int 
CCKeyDerivationPBKDF( CCPBKDFAlgorithm algorithm, const char *password, size_t passwordLen,
                      const uint8_t *salt, size_t saltLen,
                      CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm prf, uint rounds, 
                      uint8_t *derivedKey, size_t derivedKeyLen)
                      __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_NA);
```

Currently I am attempting this:

```
[DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.libSystemLibrary, EntryPoint = "CCKeyDerivationPBKDF")]
public extern static void CCKeyCerivationPBKDF(int algorithm, string password, int passwordLen,
    string salt, int saltLen, int prf, int rounds, out byte[] derivedKey, int derivedKeyLength);
```

and am getting the error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0xb9374fc61e8f9d1e: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

This is my first attempt to PInvoke something. I'm fairly certain that my signature is probably way off. What does it need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `pointer being freed was not allocated` error due to the `out` flag on the `derivedKey` parameter, just pass it as an `IntPtr` (byte[]) and Mono will marshall it correctly:

### CCKeyCerivationPBKDF signature:

```
[DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.libSystemLibrary, EntryPoint = "CCKeyDerivationPBKDF")]
public extern static int CCKeyCerivationPBKDF(
    int algorithm, 
    string password, 
    nint passwordLen,
    string salt, 
    nint saltLen, 
    UInt32 prf, 
    int rounds, 
    byte[] derivedKey, 
    int derivedKeyLength);
```

#### Example:

```
var passwordEntry = "StackOverflow";
var saltEntry = "SaltyMcSalty";
var keyBytes = new byte[32 + 1];
Array.Clear(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.Length);
var result = CCKeyCerivationPBKDF(2, passwordEntry, passwordEntry.Length, saltEntry, saltEntry.Length, 3, 1, keyBytes, keyBytes.Length);
```

#### Use "native" objects / reduced marshaling:

**(Had to due it this way to get passed on a military/aerospace certification/review)**

```
[DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.libSystemLibrary, EntryPoint = "CCKeyDerivationPBKDF")]
public extern static int CCKeyCerivationPBKDF(
    int algorithm, 
    IntPtr password, 
    nuint passwordLen,
    IntPtr salt, 
    nuint saltLen, 
    UInt32 prf, 
    nuint rounds, 
    IntPtr derivedKey, 
    nuint derivedKeyLength);
```

#### Example (w/ Base64):

```
var passwordEntry = "StackOverflow";
var passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordEntry);
var passwordBase64 =  Convert.ToBase64String(passwordBytes);
var passwordNSStringBase64 = new NSString(passwordBase64);
var passwordNSData = new NSData(passwordNSStringBase64, NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.None);

var saltEntry = "SaltyMcSalty";
var saltBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltEntry);
var saltBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
var saltNSStringBase64 = new NSString(saltBase64);
var saltNSData = new NSData(saltNSStringBase64, NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.None);

var keyBytes = new NSMutableData();
keyBytes.Length = 33;
var result = CCKeyCerivationPBKDF(2, passwordNSData.Bytes, passwordNSData.Length, saltNSData.Bytes, saltNSData.Length, 3, 1, keyBytes.MutableBytes, keyBytes.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there a reason you set your key byte array to length 33 when you pass 32 to CCKeyCerivationPBKDF?

Comment: @kspearrin You can ignore that... in that code there is an overrun check and byte #33 should always be zero after return. And there was some issue in certification due to the that fact `NSMutableData` is allowed to alloc more memory than requested (rounding up to a page size multiple). Our tax-dollars at work in the wrong way :-/